# Java - NullPointerException with JSP/Servlet sample?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, glassfish

I'm trying to get into Java again after many years. Well, I'm making a servlet sample from a tutorial using Eclipse IDE and Glassfish Server 3.1.2. The sample it's just a form sending data to another .jsp. The form is sent to the servlet, and the servlet sets a Java Bean on the output .jsp.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Encuesta de Desarrolladores</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Bienvenido a la encuesta de desarrolladores!</h1>
   <p>Indica los lenguajes de programación con los que estas familiarizado</p>
   <form action="ServletController" method="post">
      <table> 
          <tr>
            <td>Nombre Completo:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nombreCompleto" value=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Java:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLeng" value="java"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PHP:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLeng" value="php"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Python:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLeng" value="python"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ruby:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="progLeng" value="ruby"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"/></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ServletController.java**

```
package com.j2ee.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.j2ee.bean.DatosEncuesta;;


@WebServlet(name="ServletController", urlPatterns ={"/ServletController"})
public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ServletController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        func(request, response);
    }

    protected void func(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        DatosEncuesta datosEncuesta = new DatosEncuesta();
        datosEncuesta.setNombreCompleto(req.getParameter("nombreCompleto"));
        datosEncuesta.setProgLeng(req.getParameterValues("progLeng"));
        req.setAttribute("datosEncuesta", datosEncuesta);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("salida.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

**salida.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Gracias!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Gracias por cubrir nuestra encuesta!</h2>
  <p>
    <jsp:getProperty name="DatosEncuesta" property="nombreCompleto" />
    Nos has indicado que estas familiarizado con los siguientes lenguajes de programación:
    <jsp:useBean id="DatosEncuesta" scope="request" class="com.j2ee.bean.DatosEncuesta" />
   </p>
    <ul>
    <%
        System.out.println("Llegue a JSP!");
        String[] lenguajesSeleccionados = DatosEncuesta.getProgLeng();
         if(lenguajesSeleccionados != null)
         {
             for(int i=0; i<lenguajesSeleccionados.length; i++){
    %>
      <li>
         <%=lenguajesSeleccionados[i] %>
      </li>
     <% }
     }%>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I would put the java bean, but it's kind of obvious. Basically it's a string and a string[] (getters and setters included). The "DatosEncuesta" type, you see on code.

When I run this I get a NullPointerException for some reason. At first I thought it was the absence of web.xml, but I read about the annotations stuff.

Can someone help me on this one, please?

Comment: where you exactly getting nullpointer exception can you paste the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes, this line kinds of gets me the whole point:
 at com.j2ee.servlet.ServletController.func(ServletController.java:40)
 at com.j2ee.servlet.ServletController.doPost(ServletController.java:28)

But I don't get why the RequestDispatcher is generating that error? =S

Comment: Problem is resolved or not?

Comment: About the NullPointerException, yes. I'm just trying to figure out why a "null" appears printed., instead of the options sent from the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try switch the position of `jsp:useBean and jsp:getProperty`
And also, an exception trace will help people to find out where the issue is.

Comment: Cool! It worked, now that I'm into it... just one little question. In the output page, appears "null" printed in front of the <p>. Why would that be? =s

Am I misusing the bean somehow when I use the jsp tags in the output page?

Comment: try add this "<%@ page import="com.j2ee.bean.DatosEncuesta" %>" on top of jsp and see if it fix your "null" issue

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Same "null" appears printed. Besides, the useBean already has that, I think.

Comment: I found the answer! When I set the attribute in the request from the servlet, the name of the useBean id property must be the same as that attribute. Now that they match, it appears. Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 0):

**jsp:useBean** and **jsp:getProperty** is not correct way for getting values from request object. just replace your salida.jsp with below code. It will print selected checkbox from index.jsp. Let me know if there is still problem.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="com.j2ee.bean.DatosEncuesta;"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Gracias!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Gracias por cubrir nuestra encuesta!</h2>
    <p>
    <ul>

        <%
            DatosEncuesta objects = (DatosEncuesta) request.getAttribute("datosEncuesta");
        %>

        <%
            System.out.println("Llegue a JSP!");
            String[] lenguajesSeleccionados = objects.getProgLeng();
            if (lenguajesSeleccionados != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lenguajesSeleccionados.length; i++) {
        %>
        <li><%=lenguajesSeleccionados[i]%></li>
        <%
            }
            }
        %>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have just created a sample web application with above code and tested successfully.